# Scss in all WebStorm projects

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sass, webstorm

Is it possible in WebStorm to use Sass for all new/old projects without needing to go into the `settings/tools/file watchers` each time I create new project and give him file path of Sass, argument and output lines?

I'm using WebStorm on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not -- all File Watchers are project-specific entries and they are not available in Default Settings (that get applied to every brand new project).

The thing you can do right now is export/import File Watcher entries -- it's faster than specifying it manually every time.

---

Watch these tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12478
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8414